# How can I put user input inside text widget and do search in Log file with tkinter using Python

Tags: python, tkinter, search, user-input

Trying to write code for searching word in a log file `myFileMonitor.log`. Searching part is working fine but I want the user input for search to show inside the text widget in `tkinter`. Whenever I run the program the user input is going inside the terminal mode in `pycharm` and after giving the word to search, the search results are showing in the text widget (as screenshot). How can I embedded the user input inside the text widget? Novice in python.

Current result:

[image]

My code:

```
from tkinter import *

class MAIN:
    def __init__(self):
        self.watchdog = None
        self.watch_path = '.'
        self.root = Tk()
        self.messagebox = Text(width=100, height=30)
        self.root.title("KIDS")
        self.messagebox.pack()

        # Configure menu
        my_menu = Menu(self.root)
        self.root.config(menu=my_menu)

        # Create 'Report' menu items
        report_menu = Menu(my_menu, tearoff=0)
        my_menu.add_cascade(label="Report & Search", menu=report_menu)
        report_menu.add_separator()
        report_menu.add_command(label="Search", command=lambda: self.search())

        self.root.mainloop()

    def log(self, message):
        self.messagebox.insert(END, f'{message}\n')
        self.messagebox.see(END)

    # Searching based on word
    def search(self):
        try:
            """Search for the given string in file and return lines containing that string,
                    along with line numbers"""
            line_number = 0
            list_of_results = []
            file_name = 'myFileMonitor.log'
            # ------------------------------------------------------------------
            # HOW CAN I DO THIS BELOW USER INPUT INSIDE THE TEXT WIDGET & SEARCH??
            string_to_search = input("What do you want to search in the Log file? : ")
            # ------------------------------------------------------------------ 
            # Open the file in read only mode
            with open(file_name, 'r') as read_obj:
                # Read all lines in the file one by one
                for line in read_obj:
                    # For each line, check if line contains the string
                    line_number += 1
                    if string_to_search in line:
                        # If yes, then add the line number & line as a tuple in the list
                        list_of_results.append((line_number, line.rstrip()))

            # Return list of tuples containing line numbers and lines where string is found
            # print('Total matched lines : ', len(list_of_results))
            self.log(f"Total matched lines :  {len(list_of_results)} ")

            # Display matching word with line number from log file
            for element in list_of_results:
                # print('Line = ', element[0], ' :: ', element[1])
                self.log(f"Line = {element[0]}  ::  {element[1]}")

        except FileNotFoundError:
            self.log("Exception error: File not exist!")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MAIN()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put an Entry in the text widget, but that gets to be weird pretty quick, see example:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x300')

text = Text(root)
text.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
text.pack_propagate(False)  # Do not allow contents to affect size
text.insert('end', '''This is the first line.
This is the second line.
This is the third line.
This is the fourth line.
This is the fifth line.''')

entry = Entry(text, bg='wheat')
entry.pack(padx=20, pady=30, anchor='w')
entry.insert(0, "search")

root.mainloop()
```

I suggest you instead try to use a dialog for entering search criteria. Have a look at [Dialog Windows](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-dialog-windows.htm).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your idea. Find ```easygui``` and it's working splendid :)